# How to create a ranked and sorted index using dplyr?

Tags: r, indexing, dplyr

I am working on an R function that creates a ranked and sorted index with a given set of starting values (in a list) and a total number of slots to fill for the index. If the list values count is < total number of slots, then sequential numbers are inserted into the gaps. How would I modify the reproducible code provided at the bottom of this post, which accurately addresses Example 1 in the below image, so that it also covers Examples 2 and 3 in the below image?

The yellow highlighting shows the the index gaps that are to be sequentially filled (although I filled the gap for slot 5 in Example 1 using the `dplyr::dense_rank(...)` function.

Please note that Slot 1 in all cases must always = **1** or **1.1**!

Also I'm open to any improvements in the below reproducible code including completely migrating it into `dplyr`!

[image]

Reproducible code correctly gives these Example 1 results:

```
  Slot Value
1    1   1.1
2    2   1.2
3    3   2.1
4    4   2.2
5    5   3.0
```

Reproducible code:

```
library(dplyr)

# user inputs
Value <- c(2.1, 1.2, 1.1, 2.2)
totalSlots <- 5

# calculations:
Slot <- c(1:totalSlots) # set up left column of sequential numbers to use in DF
maxLength = max(length(Value), totalSlots) # calculate longer of Value or totalSlots
Value <- c(sort(Value), rep(NA, maxLength - length(Value))) # extend Value to maxLength with empty slots filled NA
indexDF <- data.frame(Slot,Value) # create DF
indexDF <- indexDF %>% mutate(Value = coalesce(Value,Slot)) # replace NA with corresponding index Slot
decimals <- indexDF[,"Value"]  - as.integer(indexDF[,"Value"]) # extract decimals for later use
rankData <- dplyr::dense_rank(as.integer(indexDF[,"Value"])) # smooth out the ranks
rankData <- rankData + decimals # add back decimals to rankData and then Value
indexDF$Value <- rankData # replace DF column with sorted and smoothed values
print.data.frame(indexDF)
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant the same code in a chain? `tibble(Value) %>% mutate(Slot = row_number()) %>% complete(Slot = seq_len(totalSlots)) %>% mutate(Value = coalesce(Value[order(Value)], Slot), Value = dense_rank(as.integer(Value)) + Value - as.integer(Value))`

Comment: Ahh thank you, very clean, concise, and understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a concise solution generating object `indexDF`, with different example scenarios for `totalSlots` and `Value` to prove it out:

```
# Example 1:
Value <- c(2.1, 1.2, 1.1, 2.2)
totalSlots <- 5

# Example 2:
Value <- c(2.1, 2.2)
totalSlots <- 3
 
# Example 3:
Value <- c(1.1, 1.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 6.1, 6.2)
totalSlots <- 10

# Example 4:
Value <- c(4.1, 4.2, 4.3)
totalSlots <- 6

indexDF <- data.frame(
  Slot = c(1:totalSlots), 
  Value = sort(c(setdiff(1:totalSlots, floor(Value)), Value))[1:totalSlots])
indexDF
```

Answer (score 0):

We could create the same codes in a pipe by expanding the data with `complete` based on the 'totalSlots', then use the same steps

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(Value) %>% 
  mutate(Slot = row_number()) %>%
  complete(Slot = seq_len(totalSlots)) %>% 
  mutate(Value = coalesce(Value[order(Value)], Slot), 
     Value = dense_rank(as.integer(Value)) + Value - as.integer(Value))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 2
   Slot Value
  <int> <dbl>
1     1   1.1
2     2   1.2
3     3   2.1
4     4   2.2
5     5   3
```